# Robust unit test for reciprocal approximation

Tags: floating-point, precision

Let $x$ and $y$ be representable floating point numbers. I'm looking for a unit test which can ensure that my user's compiler has *not* made the reciprocal approximation $\mathrm{fl}(x/y) \approx \mathrm{fl}(x)*\mathrm{fl}(1/y))$ as an optimization. However, I have been unsuccessful in coming up with a compelling example.

It's fairly easy to come up with examples where $\mathrm{fl}(x/y) \ne \mathrm{fl}(x)*\mathrm{fl}(1/y)$, e.g.

\begin{align*}
\mathrm{fl}_{64}(1.3)/\mathrm{fl}_{64}(2.9) &= \mathrm{fl}_{64}(0.4482758620689655) \\
\mathrm{fl}_{64}(1.3)*(\mathrm{fl}_{64}(1)/\mathrm{fl}_{64}(2.9)) &= \mathrm{fl}_{64}(0.4482758620689656)
\end{align*}

However, for two single numbers, the compiler might evaluate them at compile time and *not* make the reciprocal approximation, which defeats the point of my unit test to detect this. And even if the numbers are only known at runtime, single divisions are generally not optimized-only array divisions.

How can I design a sequence of double precision representables $x_i$ and a representable $y$ such that $\mathrm{fl}(x_i/y) \ne \mathrm{fl}(x_i)*\mathrm{fl}(1/y)$?

FWIW I'm using C++, though ostensibly that's of little relevance to the question.

Comment: You can enforce the evaluation at runtime if you put the numbers on the heap, e.g. via allocation with `new` (which is a keyword that's usually rarely needed in C++).

Comment: From this godbolt, I don't see a division instruction: https://godbolt.org/z/e3GaGazKT; have I misinterpreted your suggestion?

Comment: Which compiler(s) did you have in mind?  Rather than a "unit test" I would think in terms of examining the assembler output to exclude what you call "the reciprocal approximation... as an optimization."  I could illustrate this for a specific compiler (and using C++ seems relevant to me), and your purpose in excluding optimization would be nice to know.

Comment: My goal is to ensure that when a user compiles my code, then *don't* apply the reciprocal approximation. So there is no particular compiler in mind.

Comment: Your lead sentence refers to "my compiler" so the idea of trying to prevent that "when a user compiles my code" comes as a surprise (appropriate I guess for Halloween!).

Comment: @hardmath: My bad! Fixed in an edit.

Comment: @user14717: compilers are intelligent beasts ... [try with a `std::deque`] https://godbolt.org/z/KdMYaq33W), which isn't `constexpr` yet (... but probably will be soon). Thereafter, you should rely on other tricks.

Comment: @davidhigh It isn't true that a compiler cannot do the optimization just because the variable is on the heap. At the end of the day, what a compiler can and cannot do is governed by language standards, and they will not make a difference based on where a variable is stored. What you are probably implying is that variables that are on the heap may be accessed by other threads, whereas variables that are on the stack can't (though neither of these statements are actually true). The correct way to implement what you want is to mark the variable as `volatile`.

Comment: @user14717 I don't think your question is well specified. There is no `fl(x/y)` for `x=1/3`, for example because the only thing that can be expressed in floating point arithmetic is `fl(fl(x)/fl(y))`. Whether a compiler is allowed to optimize this to `fl[ fl(x) * fl(1/fl(y)) ]` is a question of what round-off error each of these operations incurs. If the letter is to within a certain tolerance of the former, then the substitution will be allowed. I will note that there are processors that do not have a floating division operation, and so the latter form may be the only one that is possible.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth: fair point, there are differences based on whether a variable is stack or heap -- consider the evolution of `constexpr` which took about ten years to provide compile-time dynamic arrays such as `std::vector` (and not yet `std::deque` which is why the godbolt example works) -- but those aren't guaranteed and the compiler is still allowed to optimize them out. `volatile` indeed is the standard approach (forgot about that because one never needs it ...)

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth: Sorry, I should've specified that x and y are representables. Edited the question, though I confess I don't know if the legibility has been enhanced.

Comment: @davidhigh: I tried with `std::deque`, but the reciprocal approximation is not generated with addition of the flags `-ffast-math`.

Comment: @user14717: my comment was just related to the statement that you can't unit test because you don't know whether the compiler does somecompile-time evaluation. As Wolfgang said, the solution in your godbolt is to set the variables x, y and z as `volatile`. I have nothing substantial to add with respect to the "reciprocal approximation" (still, my two cents: you're in a ring, and the ring operations don't commute with the floating-point representation. I don't think that one is an "approximation" whereas the other is "the real result").

Comment: @user14717 But I still don't quite get it. In the example you show, which of the two numbers is supposed to be the "correct" one, and why?

Comment: The correct answer is the one which is within half an ulp of the infinite precision result; so only one of these can be correct. I confess I had assumed the one computed with the reciprocal approximation was 1ULP off, but ostensibly we could verify this by computing in (say) quad precision. In any case, picking values for which the correct result is "obvious" is part of good unit testing, and I imagined it would be part of a good answer.

Comment: @njuffa: I do have a working fma; want to move this to an answer?

Comment: if `x = std::numeric_limits<double>::denorm_min()`, then 1.0/x blows up to infinity, but x/x evaluates to 1. even gcc can't evaluate `1.0e+0 / 4.9406564584124654e-324` at compile time

Comment: hah, i think it works https://godbolt.org/z/4bqT9nj8j

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compilers that support turning division into a multiplication with the reciprocal with some optimization flag settings (e.g. `-ffast-math` or `-fp-model=fast`) may or may not apply this to any particular division operator. It is therefore impossible to design a unit test that is 100% reliable. It is always possible that the compiler does not apply the transformation to the test case from the unit test, but *does* apply it to code one cares about.

The following assumes that a system supports the IEEE-754 (2008) floating-point standard, that the `double` type of C++ is bound to IEEE-754 `binary64` type, and that the rounding mode of "to nearest or even" is in effect. These conditions are met by most modern systems, in particular C++ environments running on x86-64 and ARM64. For the proposed technique to work, the standard math function `fma()` (C++11 or higher) must be available, and must be correctly implemented, preferably by mapping to a corresponding hardware instruction, as spme `fma()` implementations based on software emulation have been found to be faulty.

Correct rounding of a division `q = x / y` can be checked by computing the residual x - q * y accurately with the help of a fused multiply-add (FMA): `residual = fma (q, -y, x)`. If we choose to divide by `3.0`, residuals of dividends that are consecutive `binary64` encodings form a repeating pattern that repeats every three dividends. One third of cases result in a positive residual, one third result in a negative residual, and one third has a zero residual. The code below simply checks these statistics instead of examining the pattern in detail. It also checks whether the residual is bigger than would be expected from division with round-to-nearest-or-even. If division is replaced by multiplication with the reciprocal, both of these checks (residual statistics, maximum residual magnitude) will fail.

For some divisors, it is possible to correctly compute the quotient of a floating-point division by compile-time literal constant without using a division operation, and this includes the case `x / 3.0`. I am not aware of a compiler that currently does this. To prevent a compiler from discovering the compile-time constant divisor of `3.0`, it would therefore be highly advisable to prevent inlining of `is_division_correctly_rounded()`. Compilers typically offer toolchain-specific function attributes for this, e.g. `__attribute__((noinline))`, `__declspec(noinline)`.

Note that hexadecimal floating-point literals were added in C++17, so the code below should be compiled accordingly.

````c
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>

#define NBR_PER_CASE   (100)
#define NBR_TEST_CASES (3 * NBR_PER_CASE)

int is_division_correctly_rounded (double dividend, double divisor, double eps)
{
    int count_less = 0;
    int count_more = 0;
    int count_equal = 0;
    int count_too_big = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < NBR_TEST_CASES; i++) {
        double quotient = dividend / divisor;
        double residual = fma (quotient, -divisor, dividend);
        count_less += (residual == -eps);
        count_more += (residual == +eps);
        count_equal += (residual == 0.0);
        count_too_big += (fabs (residual) > eps);
        dividend = nextafter (dividend, INFINITY);
    };
    return ((count_less == NBR_PER_CASE) && (count_more == NBR_PER_CASE) &&
            (count_equal == NBR_PER_CASE) && (count_too_big == 0)) ? 1 : 0;
}

int main (void)
{
    if (is_division_correctly_rounded (2.5, 3.0, 0x1.0p-53)) {
        printf ("division appears to be correctly rounded to nearest-even\n");
    } else {
        printf ("division NOT correctly rounded to nearest-even\n");
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```
````